# ubuntu MD5SUM hash doesnt match, now how to repair the iso image?

Tags: downloads, boot-repair, error-handling, md5sum, hash

I have checked MD5SUM hash for the downloaded Ubuntu desktop 14.04 and it didn't match.
I have downloaded the file from official website without using any client like utorrent etc. How can I repair the errors in ISO image? I found out about Zsync which repairs ISO images without downloading whole file, but it doesn't run on Windows. I am on Windows XP. Is there any app that can repair ISO files?
Or is there a Zsync app version that can be used in Windows? 
Or is using torrent client likely to result in a good download? 
Or do I have to download the image all over again?

Comment: suggest you redownload the ISO, if there is information missing in the iso, you can't just 'fix it'.

Comment: @Minos : how to get a good download? should I use torrent client? because it take 6 hours to download and it would be frustrating if second download is also not good. i use windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

Download it again via bittorrent. It's a better way.

For many years, I always download Linux distros using bittorrent and always check the checksums. I can't remember any mismatch.

Comment: sure, i use vuze client for downloading torrent. bittorrent and utorrent doesn't work on my system. Is vuze able to give a good download?

Comment: I shouldn't matter too much which torrent program you use. So use whatever you are familiar with. The advantage of torrents is also that you can verify file integrity  without having to re-download everything if something is wrong.